# Start a windows forms application before log on to windows

Tags: windows, winforms, winlogon

How can i start a windows forms application before log on to windows? Is is possible to start a windows forms application before log on to windows? If it's not, do i have a chance to start a windows service before log on and invoke a windows forms application from the service that is already started before log on?

Comment: If a user isn't logged on, what benefit is a _form_ going to have?

Comment: I had a huge code and don't want to port the project to windows service application.

Comment: If you want it to run under the context of the computer and doesn't need a user's input or feedback, I strongly suggest refactoring it to run as a service. you _could_ use [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) and start the application from the service, but the whole essence of a form application is to the user can interact; this component will be missing if it's run as a service.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will port it to windows service in time but immidiately, i have to do like this if it's possible. Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments to the question you want to run a standard desktop app, built with WinForms, not a service, that starts before the user has logged on.

This is not possible. What you need is a service.

Answer (score 2):

**Very** basic, but should give you the gist. You also need to create a `ServiceProcessInstaller` for it (along with making a call to `installutil`).

```
public class WinFormHostService : System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase
{
  [STAThread]
  public static void Main()
  {
    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(new WinFormHostService());
  }

  protected Process winFormsProcess;

  public WinFormHostService()
  {
    this.ServiceName = "WinForm Host Service";
    this.AutoLog = true;
  }

  protected override void OnStart(String[] args)
  {
    this.winFormsProcess = new Process();
    try
    {
      this.winFormsProcess.UseShellExecute = false;
      this.winFormsProcess.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe";
      this.winFormsProcess.CreateNoWindow = true;
      this.winFormsProcess.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // unable to start process
    }
  }
}
```

This is basically like hosting a WCF service from a windows service, so if you need more details look up "WCF windows service host" (or alike) and see [how that's done](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx). Same premise, you're just using a `Process` instead.